# Create table as ... select with joins

Tags: postgresql, ddl, postgresql-9.5

Do i have to use two queries or is that possible to write "as select" here?

I put the query like my colleague wrote it, and it currently works in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE planification_client_biens_test
(nom VARCHAR(50),
serveur VARCHAR(24),
scheduled_backup VARCHAR(8),
schedule VARCHAR(31),
retention VARCHAR(6),
groupe VARCHAR(200),
remote_access VARCHAR(433),
alias VARCHAR(332),
parallelisme VARCHAR(3),
storage_nodes VARCHAR(69),
client_OS_type VARCHAR(31),
version_networker VARCHAR(19),
savesets VARCHAR(4200),
ALIAS_1 VARCHAR(50),
ALIAS_2 VARCHAR(50),
APPLICATION VARCHAR(255),
ENVIRONNEMENT VARCHAR(50),
IMPACT VARCHAR(20),
CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL VARCHAR(50),
TYPE VARCHAR(13),
SITE VARCHAR(30),
COMPOSANT_DE VARCHAR(23),
COMPOSE_DE VARCHAR(17),
ETAT VARCHAR(30),
POIDS DECIMAL(11,2),
EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION VARCHAR(100))
SELECT t1.*, t2.ALIAS_1, t2.ALIAS_2,t2.APPLICATION,t2.ENVIRONNEMENT, t2.IMPACT, t2.CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL, t2.TYPE, t2.SITE, t2.COMPOSANT_DE, t2.COMPOSE_DE, t2.ETAT, t2.POIDS, t2.EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION FROM planification_client_test t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Biens_test t2 ON t1.nom_court IN (t2.NOM,t2.ALIAS_1,t2.ALIAS_2);
```

I obviously tried to do that, but got an error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: ...AR(50), calendrier VARCHAR(50), commentaire TEXT) AS SELECT ...
                                                             ^
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify data types for the columns when using `create table as`.

```
CREATE TABLE planification_client_biens_test
(
  nom,
  serveur,
  scheduled_backup,
  schedule,
  retention,
  groupe,
  remote_access,
  alias,
  parallelisme,
  storage_nodes,
  client_OS_type,
  version_networker,
  savesets,
  ALIAS_1,
  ALIAS_2,
  APPLICATION,
  ENVIRONNEMENT,
  IMPACT,
  CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL,
  TYPE,
  SITE,
  COMPOSANT_DE,
  COMPOSE_DE,
  ETAT,
  POIDS,
  EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION
)
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.ALIAS_1, 
       t2.ALIAS_2,
       t2.APPLICATION,
       t2.ENVIRONNEMENT, 
       t2.IMPACT, 
       t2.CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL, 
       t2.TYPE, 
       t2.SITE, 
       t2.COMPOSANT_DE, 
       t2.COMPOSE_DE, 
       t2.ETAT, 
       t2.POIDS, 
       t2.EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION 
FROM planification_client_test t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Biens_test t2 ON t1.nom_court IN (t2.NOM,t2.ALIAS_1,t2.ALIAS_2);
```

The data types are inferred from the source columns in the query.

If you need to change the type between the source and the created table, you need to cast the columns in the query, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE planification_client_biens_test
(
 ....
)
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.ALIAS_1, 
       t2.ALIAS_2,
       cast(t2.APPLICATION as  VARCHAR(255)),
       t2.ENVIRONNEMENT, 
       t2.IMPACT, 
       t2.CLIENT_OPERATIONNEL, 
       cast(t2.TYPE as varchar(13)), 
       t2.SITE, 
       cast(t2.COMPOSANT_DE as VARCHAR(23)), 
       cast(t2.COMPOSE_DE as VARCHAR(17)), 
       t2.ETAT, 
       t2.POIDS, 
       t2.EQUIPE_EXPLOITATION 
FROM planification_client_test t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Biens_test t2 ON t1.nom_court IN (t2.NOM,t2.ALIAS_1,t2.ALIAS_2);
```

Comment: I didn't know you cannot specify data types in this case.
It now tells me : "column "poids" specified more than once". I suppose i have to delete t2.poids from the query?

Comment: @B3nSp1ndl3r: that shouldn't happen if you use the first example in my answer specifying column names as part of the CREATE TABLE. If you left out the column names from that, I guess that `planification_client_test` also has a column named `poids` that you need rename

Comment: ok, i'll drop that table, recreate it and follow your advices. ty horse